# Where have all my inodes gone?

Tags: debian, inode

Today, I ran out of inodes on one of my VPSs.
I deleted a bunch of superfluous small files, freeing enough inodes to make the system operational again:

```
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/simfs       586K  529K   58K   91% /
```

I also hacked together a short command to give me the number of used inodes (essentially listing all files with their inode numbers, filtering out duplicates and counting the lines of the result):

```
sudo find / -xdev -type f -printf '%i~%P\n' > files.txt
<files.txt | sort -u -t'~' -k1,1 > inodes.txt
wc -l files.txt inodes.txt
```

```
1513608 files.txt  
275320 inodes.txt
```

So it looks like the files on `/` only account for 275k inodes, but `df` reports 529k used.

How can that be?

<sub>(I even restarted the system to free any inodes that were still locked by processes, but that didn't change the amount of used inodes at all.)</sub>

Comment: directories have also inodes, try again w/o `-type f`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a bind mount instead of `-xdev`. Also, directories use inodes too.

```
mkdir /mnt/somewhere
mount -o bind / /mnt/somewhere
find /mnt/somewhere -printf '%i\n' | sort -u | wc -l
```

Comment: Curious about the `-xdev` suggestion. Why is that?

Comment: @JoelDavis Probably to make sure there aren't files hidden under a mount point.

Comment: Options like `-xdev`, `--one-file-system`, etc. never give the complete picture. You should never use them on principle if you can help it.

Comment: I used `-xdev` to exclude files on mountpoints like `/tmp`. However I didn't think of mountpoints "shadowing" files on the rootfs, so thanks for the hint to use a bind mount.